# What is an alternative of FILTER function for other than office365 excel?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet like

| SKU | ITEM_ID | LINE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | CCC |
| 111 | 2 | NNN |

I need to filter rows based on value of LINE column. In office365 it can easily be done by FILTER function. I have to use excel 2007. What can be a good alternative to create function to filter here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$3,SMALL(IF(--($C$1:$C$3="CCC"),ROW($C$1:$C$3)),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")` array formula to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` in versions prior to office 365. Copy down the formula and to the right to your needs. The ROWS-part of the function will behave as a counter for 1st, 2nd, etc match for the condition.

You can adjust the ranges, but make sure to adjust all three:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$[number of end of range],SMALL(IF(--($C$1:$C$[same number as before]="CCC"),ROW($C$1:$C$[same number as before])),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")`

Comment: Just got second thoughts on the column part of the index to work in versions older than office 365. Updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is skipping some rows.

Comment: Did you adjust the ranges correctly? It should work https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrFAd.jpg

Comment: @P.b I found out that modifying your approach, there is no need to copy down the formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A3, SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$3="CCC", ROW(A1:A3)), ROW(A1:A3))),"")`. This is for filtering by one column only, but I guess it works for more than one column

Comment: @DavidLeal I know, but that only spills in Office365 and then we typically use FILTER instead.

Comment: yes, @P.b I was not sure about that, I don't have a way to test older versions. I thought this array behavior for some of the functions has backward compatibility, I am not sure if it is in all cases. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal It calculates the same, so you would be able to for instance INDEX the array as `=INDEX([your-array-version],2)` and it would show the second result of the array (not sure if it requires ctrl+shift+enter). But older versions never spill results over cells (it only stores the array in memory)