# How do I filter data in Excel by comparing pairs in columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to filter a list of cryptocurrency coins by comparing two columns. My goal is to find all coins that have a BTC pair, but cannot have a USDT pair. It may have any other possible pair. I have added an example to this post to show what I am looking for.

- COIN_A is invalid because it contains a USDT pair;
- COIN_B is valid because it only contains a BTC pair;
- COIN_C is valid because it contains a BTC pair and no USDT pair (any other pair is okay);
- COIN_D is invalid because it does not have a BTC pair;[image]

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? VBA? or excel Formula?

Comment: A formula would be easier so that I can also use it in Numbers on my Mac :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Excel 365, you can use FILTER. This approach, uses LET to avoid helper cells and illustrates the method:

```
=LET(coins, A2:A8,
     pairs, B2:B8,
      btc_coins, FILTER(coins,pairs="BTC"),
      usdt_coins, FILTER(coins,pairs="USDT"),
      FILTER(btc_coins, ISNA(MATCH(btc_coins, usdt_coins, 0))) )
```

Where A2:A8 is your COIN column and B2:B8 is your PAIR column.

[image: result]

A non-Excel 365 approach will be more involved with INDEX and SMALL.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I don't use Office 365, though. I will take a look at INDEX and SMALL to make this work in Google Sheets. Appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little sketchy on GoogleSheets, but I think it would work with ArrayFormula. This answer from P.b. might be workable in Gsheets, but I am not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68419135/what-is-an-alternative-of-filter-function-for-other-than-office365-excel

Comment: Thanks! I will mark yours as the solution because it answers my question (and potentially does for Google Sheets and Numbers).