# Excel filtering data

Tags: excel, filtering, excel-2010

I need help.

I have a thousand rows in 1 column. Each rows either end with a digit or a letter. And this letter ranges from A until RR. How can I select all the values that end with digit only?

Your help is much appreciated. Please respect my post.

I tried to used "not ending with" option in Filter. But i can only have 2. Is there a way to range the filter values from A through RR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input data is in column **A**, I consider the entire column, but you can adjust it to your specific range, then you can use:

```
=FILTER(A:A, ISNUMBER(-RIGHT(A:A,1)))
```

It returns the rows from column **A** that ends with a single digit. We use the minus sign (`-`)to convert a text into a number. If it is not a number returns `#VALUE!` and in that case `ISNUMBER` returns `FALSE`, otherwise it returns `TRUE`.

If your Excel version doesn't support `FILTER` function, the following answer to the question: [What is an alternative of FILTER function for other than office365 excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68419135/what-is-an-alternative-of-filter-function-for-other-than-office365-excel) provided by @P.b can be adapted to your case as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(-RIGHT(A:A,1)),ROW(A:A)),
 ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Then just expand it down.

Please take into account that **using the entire column is not efficient**, better to adapt it to your specific range. Using a specific range for example `A1:A3`. The previous formula can be modified to return the entire array, there is no need to expand it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A3,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(-RIGHT(A1:A3,1)),ROW(A1:A3)),
 ROW(A1:A3))),"")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the immediate response. However, im using excel 2010 and i got an error where FILTER function is invalid

Comment: I guess I didn't see the tag, or it was added after my response. Let me try to provide a solution that works for your version

Comment: Really grateful for your help, been working and searching for the solution, i cant thank you enough for helping me with it

Comment: I tried it on excel online, filter is available however it returned #CALC! all the way down

Comment: just to make sure the formula is working and no issue with the input data, try this: `=FILTER({"textA";"text1";"text2"}, ISNUMBER(-RIGHT({"textA";"text1";"text2"},1)))`

Comment: @dragonaire I am glad it worked. I added a non `FILTER` approach in case it helps